# IPhone+performselector in background

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can anyone help me with `performSelectorInBackground`? I want to reload table with updated data in `performSelectorInBackground`.

Comment: No UI updates in background. UI changes must be performed on main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is you just get the data in the background thread and you can return back to main thread once you get the data and update the tableview in main thread.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //All your views cell creations and other stuff
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadDataThatToBeFetchedInThread:) 
                          withObject:objectArrayThatNeedToFetchData];
}

- (void) loadDataThatToBeFetchedInThread:(NSArray *)objectThatNeedToFetchData
{
    //Fetch the data here. which takes place in background thread
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTableViewWithTheData:) 
                           withObject:responseData 
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
}


- (void) updateTableViewWithTheData:(NSMutableArray *)yourData
{
    //Update Data to tableview here
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry i can only give one +1 :)

Comment: ^Thank you very much,I will certainly give it a try

Answer (score 0):

All the UI functionalities should be done in the main thread. So you have to reload the UITableView in main thread only.

Comment: Looks like a great comment! But maybe you have a look at the question!